# How to setup Dotproject for software development projects?

Tags: dotproject

I am assessing some tools to manage software develpment projects. Dotproject seems a good one, but i would like to learn of other's experinces using it for software development.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) for a small team and loving it. The web interface is very elegant, and it gives me power and simplicity at the same time.

My favorite feature is the strong ticketing system which allows me to create tickets on the web, assign them to developers, associate them with other tickets, estimate the time it takes to close the ticket, and aggregate those times graphically. It really shines, though, with its version control and ticket integration. Being able to specify that this commit is related to ticket #45, fixes bug #78, and closes ticket #32 is very nice.

They offer version control hosting for multiple version control systems - including SVN and GIT.

They offer free and paid packages.

For more information, check out their usage videos [here](http://www.assembla.com/features/videos).

*Oh, and do let us know what you decide and why :)*

Comment: Thanks, Assembla looks nice. However, I am looking for a more Gantt like project management tool. I would like the ability to have a projects dashboard while at the same time having programmers reporting their timesheets and updating their tasks. Document sharing would also be a useful feature. Dotproject has them all, but not sure if it is being applied in a production system already. I am concern on it's robustness and how secure it is to handle confidential information.

Comment: Assembla has these features - I started to allude to that with ticket visualization. There are quite a few plugins that can be enabled for your project, and an account is free. I suggest you start one and check them out.

Comment: I tend to favor Dotproject in terms of connectivity. I mean, being it open source and php, it can be easily extended to interface directly to your production environment. It will take some effort but so far I haven't found something that matches all what I envision on a project management tool for software development.

Answer (score 0):

An old post, I know...

I used to be a core member of the dotproject team and used it for years and set up many organizations on it... ranging from small non-profits and software shops to major government projects.  It tended to work relatively well.  Unfortunately, due to the crawl of development, half the dotproject team split to form web2project and we've been there almost two years.

At present, we (web2project) does a quarterly release and have done *major* work on the code.  We've closed ~100+ bugs, added dozens of features like iCal feeds, and improved performance by 95% and cut about 1/3 of the code overall.  And yes, we have an upgrade path from dotProject.